# How to convert a date from a character string?

Tags: r, date

I have searched but I could not find out how to convert a date from a character string formatted as follows:

```
date <- "07-21-2015-09:30AM"
```

I wanted to use `as.Date`, but I have not manage to. All I get is the following:

```
as.Date(date, format="%m-%d-%y-%hAM")
NA

as.Date(dates, format="%m-%d-%y-%h")
NA
```

Comment: If you need the date just do `as.Date(date, format='%m-%d-%Y')#[1] "2015-07-21"
`

Comment: I need the time too...

Comment: In that case, you should use `as.POSIXct`/`strptime` etc. `as.POSIXct(date, format='%m-%d-%Y-%I:%M%p')`

Comment: Thanks @akrun! Where can you find documentation on date format in R?

Comment: @Pop You can check most of the format from `?strptime`

Comment: All that I needed! Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we need the 'date' and 'time', one option is `as.POSIXct`

```
 as.POSIXct(date, format='%m-%d-%Y-%I:%M%p')
 #[1] "2015-07-21 09:30:00 EDT"
```

Comment: @RHertel It works with `strptime`, but it may be easier to store with `as.POSIXct` as the `strptime` returns `POSIXlt` class

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the lubridate package like this:

```
library('lubridate')
date <- "07-21-2015-09:30AM"
mdy_hm(date)
# "2015-07-21 09:30:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 1):

I like `strptime` for this:

```
strptime(date, format="%m-%d-%Y-%R%p")
#[1] "2015-07-21 09:30:00 EDT"
```

And in the case that you needed to see the date in the same format as entered, you can call the related `strftime`. It doesn't change the internal storage of the variable, rather it changes the format only.

```
strftime(xx, format="%m-%d-%Y-%R%p")
#[1] "07-21-2015-09:30AM"
```